# A function that is equal to zero at all points except one is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Let $c$ be inside $(a,b)$ and let $d$ be inside the set of all real numbers. Define $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ as
$$f(x):=\cases{d\quad& if $x$ is equal to c\cr 0& if $x$ is not equal to c\cr}\ $$ Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable and compute  $\displaystyle \int \limits_{a}^{b}f$ using the definition of the integral.

---

To show it is Reimann integrable I know I have to show that   $\sup  L(p,f) =\inf U(p,f) $  (notation-wise this mean the $\sup$ (lower Darboux Sum) = $\inf$ (upper Darboux Sum)).

I am running into confusion determining these values though. I know $L(p,f)=0$ and I have $U(p,f)=d(b-a)$. Is this correct? If so how do I determine the $\sup$ and $\inf$?

Comment: The error is when stating that `U(p,f)=d(b-a)`. This is incorrect, unless `p` is the trivial subdivision `{a,b}`.

Comment: then what would U(p,f) be? I am running into confusion with determining it when I am working with an arbitrary number d.

Comment: `U(p,f)=dw(p)` where `w(p)` denotes the length of the interval of the subdivision `p` containing `c`. (Unrelated: please use `@` in comments.)

Comment: @Did so then how would I go about determine what the inf of that is? I know it would have to be 0 because the sup of L(p,f) is 0 since the whole thing is 0?

Comment: Use subdivisions `p` such that `w(p)` goes to zero.

Comment: @Did I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: If `w(p)` goes to zero, `U(p,f)` goes to zero. Since `L(p,f)=0` for every `p`, this shows the Riemann integral `R(f)` of `f` exists and that its value is zero.

Comment: @Did so then if I show that L(p,f)=U(p,f)=0 would that then solve the second part of the question? Meaning would the integral of f from a to b then be 0?

Comment: There is no `p` such that `U(p,f)=0`. Please review the definition of Riemann integrability.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Details depend on precisely how the Riemann integral is presented, so this can only be a guide.

Take a partition $\Pi$ of the interval $[a,b]$. Then any Riemann sum $S$ based on $\Pi$ satisfies the inequality 
$$0\le S\le \epsilon d,$$
where $\epsilon$ is the *mesh* of the partition, that is, the maximum length of the subintervals of $\Pi$.

As $\epsilon\to 0$, $S\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful things to note:

This also works if a function disagrees with $0$ at finitely many points, just repeat Andre's argument $n$ times, surrounding each point of issue by an interval

$\frac{\epsilon}{nM}$ where $n$ is the number of points and $M$ is the max of these points (this may be done as it is finite list).

Notice that this stems from a more general issue that if $f \in \mathcal{R}$ and we define a set $ \{x_1, \ldots, x_k \}$, then we may define

$$g(x) : = \begin{cases}
f(x) \qquad x \notin J \\
d_i \qquad x = x_i
\end{cases}$$

Then we can prove that $g \in \mathcal{R}$ and even that $$\int_{[a,b]} f \, dx = \int_{[a,b]} g \, dx.$$

In fact, this even works if, say, $f$ and $g$ disagree on all of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b]$!

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: But the Dirichlet function is not Riemann integrable!